# Clearing and rewriting slice in loop

Tags: go, slice

I am wondering what the "most" correct way is to delete a slice in my use case is. I have a for loop where I can function which returns a slice, then that slice is appended to a bigger slice. Each time the for loop is called the smaller slice should be empty. I can't just overwrite the slice with the values returned because I need to know the length.

I get the expected output, but don't know if I can run into errors with memory leaks or getting bad data.
Is it best to set the slice as nil, make a new slice, or something else?

https://play.golang.org/p/JxMKaFQAPWL

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func populateSlice(offset int) []string {
    letters := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "OP", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}
    toReturn := make([]string, 0)

    if len(letters)-offset <= 0 {
        toReturn = nil
    } else if len(letters) < offset+10 {
        remaining := len(letters) - offset
        toReturn = letters[offset:remaining+offset]
    } else {
        toReturn = letters[offset:10+offset]
    }

    fmt.Printf("toReturn: %#v\n", toReturn)
    return toReturn

}

func main() {

    offset := 0
    bigSlice := make([]string, 0)

    for {

        smallSlice := populateSlice(offset)

        bigSlice = append(bigSlice, smallSlice...)

        if smallSlice == nil || len(smallSlice) < 5 {
            fmt.Printf("break: len(smallSlice): %v", len(smallSlice))
            break
        }
        offset += len(smallSlice)

        fmt.Printf("smallSlice: %#v\n", smallSlice)
        fmt.Printf("bigSlice: %#v\n\n", bigSlice)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, simplify your code,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func populateSlice(offset int) []string {
    letters := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "OP", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}
    lo, hi := offset, offset+10
    if hi > len(letters) {
        hi = len(letters)
    }
    if lo < 0 || lo >= hi {
        return nil
    }
    return letters[lo:hi:hi]
}

func main() {
    var bigSlice []string
    for offset := 0; ; {
        smallSlice := populateSlice(offset)
        fmt.Printf("smallSlice: %#v\n", smallSlice)
        if len(smallSlice) == 0 {
            break
        }
        bigSlice = append(bigSlice, smallSlice...)
        offset += len(smallSlice)
    }
    bigSlice = bigSlice[:len(bigSlice):len(bigSlice)]
    fmt.Printf("bigSlice: %#v\n", bigSlice)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/sRqazV_luol

Output:

```
smallSlice: []string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"}
smallSlice: []string{"k", "l", "m", "n", "OP", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u"}
smallSlice: []string{"v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}
smallSlice: []string(nil)
bigSlice: []string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "OP", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}
```

There are no slices to delete. There are no memory leaks. Go has a garbage collector. There is no bad data.